# how to find out the water consumption rate based on the water levels in sump and tank?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, prediction, arima

Before i predicted the future water consumption rate using ARIMA Model. But now i has to find out and predict the water consumption based on the levels in the tank and the sump.I have the hardware which is measuring the level of sump and tank. I know, i should know the dimension and have to calculate the volume. But not getting how to predict using ARIMA model python. please someone guide me with code. thanks

Output must be present and future prediction based on the water level in the sump and the tank.